# Extract a pair with same values in a list of dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to extract all the  dictionaries from a list such that a pair of keys has same value.

```
DictList=[{"name1":"ABC","name2":"JKL","pos":1},{"name1":"GHI","name2":"ASD", "pos":2},{"name1":"JKL","name2":"ABC","pos":3}]

Output:[{name1:ABC,name2:JKL,pos:1}, {name1:JKL,name2:ABC,pos:3}]
```

here the keys name1 and name2 has the same pair of  values  ABC,JKL .

This is how I started, but this does not seem to be an  efficient approach

```
ListPairs=[]
for dict1 in DictList:
    name1=dict1["name1"]
    name2=dict1["name2"]
    for dict2 in  DictList:
         if dict2["name1"]==name1 and dict2["name2"]==name2  or dict2["name2"]==name1 and dict2["name1"]==name2:
            if (dict1,dict2) not in ListPairs and dict1 != dict2:
                  ListPairs.add((dict1,dict2))
```

Comment: Do the matching keys have to be `("name1", "name2")`? What if `("name1", "pos")` matched?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to find `dict`s that contain certain values?

Comment: The matching keys are fixed. pos is actually unique across all  records and I  finally want to get the pos numbers for which the keys (name1 and name2) match.

Comment: These keys represent a pair of authors and I want to extract all items that have same pair of authors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to group dictionaries which have the same set of "name1" and "name2" keys, regardless of order. This should accomplish just that:

```
d = defaultdict(lambda: [])

for x in DictList:
    s = frozenset((x["name1"], x["name2"]))
    d[s].append(x)
```

So that, for example:

```
for key, value in d.items():
    print key, value
```

prints:

```
frozenset(['GHI', 'ASD']) [{'name2': 'ASD', 'pos': 2, 'name1': 'GHI'}]
frozenset(['JKL', 'ABC']) [{'name2': 'JKL', 'pos': 1, 'name1': 'ABC'}, 
                           {'name2': 'ABC', 'pos': 3, 'name1': 'JKL'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

If **any** two keys can match:

```
import itertools

def checkDicts(d1, d2):
    for k1,k2 in itertools.combinations(d1.keys(), 2):
        if k2 not in d2:
            continue
        if d1[k1] == d2[k2]:
            return True
    return False

def getPairs(L):
    for d1,d2 in itertools.combinations(L, 2):
        if checkDicts(d1,d2):
            yield d1,d2
```

Output:

```
In [126]: L = [{"name1":"ABC","name2":"JKL","pos":1},{"name1":"GHI","name2":"ASD", "pos":2},{"name1":"JKL","name2":"ABC","pos":3}]

In [127]: for d1,d2 in getPairs(L):
   .....:     print(d1, d2)
   .....:     
{'pos': 1, 'name2': 'JKL', 'name1': 'ABC'} {'pos': 3, 'name2': 'ABC', 'name1': 'JKL'}
```

**EDIT**: From one of your comments on your OP, it seems that you are looking for pairs of dicts that share the same values for two specific keys. This is a little easier than the problem solved by the above code:

```
def checkDicts(d1,d2):
    return set([d1['name1'], d1['name2']]) == set([d2['name1'], d2['name2']])
```

Output:

```
In [130]: L = [{"name1":"ABC","name2":"JKL","pos":1},{"name1":"GHI","name2":"ASD", "pos":2},{"name1":"JKL","name2":"ABC","pos":3}]

In [131]: for d1,d2 in getPairs(L):
    print(d1, d2)
   .....:     
{'pos': 1, 'name2': 'JKL', 'name1': 'ABC'} {'pos': 3, 'name2': 'ABC', 'name1': 'JKL'}
```